# installing mod_wsgi giving 403 error

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

installing mod_wsgi giving 403 error

**httpd.conf i added code below**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "C:/xampp/www/htdocs/wsgi_app/wsgi_handler.py"

   <Directory "C:/xampp/www/htdocs/wsgi_app/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**wsgi_handler.py**

```
status = ‘200 OK’
output = ‘Hello World!’
response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
start_response(status, response_headers)
return [output]
```

**Note: localhost is my virtual host domain and it is working fine but when i request `http://localhost/wsgi/` got 403 error.**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/htdocs/localhost"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Error log

```
[Wed Jul 04 06:01:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/www/htdocs/localhost/favicon.ico
[Wed Jul 04 06:01:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/Bin/apache
[Wed Jul 04 06:01:58 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: C:/xampp/www/htdocs/wsgi_app/wsgi_handler.py
[Wed Jul 04 06:01:58 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/Bin/apache
[Wed Jul 04 06:01:58 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/www/htdocs/localhost/favicon.ico
[Wed Jul 04 06:01:58 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/Bin/apache
```

**Note: My apache is not in c:/xampp/bin/apache it is in c:/xampp/bin/server-apache/**

Comment: Got error logs?

Comment: Questions typically involve a question mark somewhere.

Comment: Normally you would have the WSGIScriptAlias and Directory block inside of the VirtualHost not outside. This would restrict it to that one virtual host.

Answer (score 3):

You're using different directories in your <Directory> and you <VirtualHost> directives.

In your Directory directive you've got

```
 <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi_app/">
```

In the VirtualHost you've got

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/htdocs/localhost"
```

You need to fix it so the access rules and the DocumentRoot agree on the directory you want to use.

Comment: ok i will try and inform you.

Comment: i fixed but still getting 403 error,My apache is not in c:/xampp/bin/apache it is in c:/xampp/bin/server-apache/

Comment: There are three errors in your log. 1) ExecCGI isn't set, se the answer by tfitzgerald. 2) You don't have a favicon.ico, this one you can disregard. 3) Somewhere you have some configuration pointing at c:/xampp/Bin/apache - search for that string in your config file (it may be your DocumentRoot) and replace it with the directory where you actually store your files.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that Options ExecCGI is off for the `c:/xampp/www/htdocs/wsgi_app/wsgi_handler.py` directory.

Have you tried turning Options ExecCGI on? Change `Options None` to `Options +ExecCGI`

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowing access to the document root, just the WSGI root.

Add this within your `<VirtualHost *:80>` block:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/www/htdocs/localhost">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```